# A is C, not B - Is this expression correct?

Tags: sentence-structure

When *A* is not *B* but *C*, can I use "A is C, not B" ? For example:

> Apple **is** American, **not** Korean.

Do native English speakers use this kind of expression?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes a sentence like the following:

> Apple is American, not Korean.

is perfectly correct!

You can also use as an alternative:

> Apple is not Korean, it is American!

Comment: Thank you so much Ced. It was very helpful. Have a great day~

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't forget to upvote if you found it useful :)

Comment: In general the only time we use "American" to describe a *language* is out of irony, or frequently, ignorance.  Americans speak **English**, more or less.

Comment: @Andrew, what are you talking about? Where was American used as a language?

Comment: It's an elision: "Apple is American, *(Apple is)* not Korean."

Comment: @Andrew it seems like they are talking about the brand/technology company Apple, not the word "apple" in English.

Comment: @Mixolydian   Ah.  Well in that case ignore me  :)

Comment: While the grammar is correct, the sentence doesn't make sense unless it's in the context provided by @Andrew. I would be better to say 'Apple is an American company, not a Korean one, if that's what is meant.